# Heroku - How do I update dependencies?

Tags: python, heroku, dependencies, flask, pypi

So I have an API hosted on Heroku - https://github.com/karan/HNify. A few days ago, I updated one of it's dependencies and pushed the update to pypi (I own the dependency). I then pushed the new version of the API (with updated version of dependency in requirements.txt) to heroku, but the change hasn't been reflected. How do I do it?

Comment: No one knows how to fix this?

Comment: It looks ok. Have you seen logs?

Comment: I don't see anything about the actual installed version of the dependency in the logs.

Comment: Hm... no luck. May be make some debug page, gather `pip freeze` output and show it?

Comment: Oh wait it's updated now. Guess it takes Heroku 2 days to update dependencies?

Comment: I suppose you've made more changes to `requirements.txt` and this time heroku noticed them